# Error while Saving Record using Angular Code

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created an ASP.NET Core Web API project and Angular frontend to insert data into a database.

This is the code in my `dept.service.ts` file:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeptService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:7216/api/departments/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  SaveDept(dept: any): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post<Department>(this.baseUrl+'SaveDept', dept).pipe(
      map((response: any)=> {
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Called the above Angular service inside the component using this code:

```
SaveDept(): void {
    this.deptService.SaveDept(this.model).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        console.log('Department details saved successfully');
      },
      error: error => console.log(error)
    });
```

By the way, my `Department` entity was defined like this:

```
export interface Department {
    deptName: string,
    location: string
}
```

When debugging the above code, execution is not hitting the Web API controller. I am getting below error. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue!

[image: Unable to save record using Angular code]

Regards,
Ashok Kumar K.

Comment: The error is quite explicit : 404, the route doesn't exist on your backend.

Comment: If use .NET as backend use `SaveDest([FromBody] Department department){...}` and check the variables (in general .NET expect a model in pascalCase so you should have a class with properties:`DeptName` and `Location`). Check also if the route are defined and the back-end is running.

Comment: Status code 404 means the server cannot find the requested resource.You can check if the URL used in baseUrl matches the route you defined in your ASP.NET Core Web API project.And check that your server side routing configuration has the relevant routing properties set correctly to handle the request correctly. In addition to that, if your frontend and backend are on different ports, you can check that you have the correct configuration to Allow cross-origin requests.